# How to install Oracle JDK 14 on ubuntu 18.04 and make it be used by java applications?

Tags: jdk

there is answer for old versions here: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

but there is a .deb file here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html

Answer (score 2):

install the .deb file easily with `gdebi-gtk`

now, below, attention to the path, `jdk-14.0.1` may differ:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin/java 2
sudo update-alternatives --config java # select it now

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin/javac 2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin/jar 2
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin/jar

java -version;javac -version #confirm it
```

based on info at:
https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-14-on-ubuntu-18-04-16-04/